# How to prevent hibernate log to my console (eclipse and tomcat general log)?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, log4j

I tried to log the SQL output of Hibernate into a specific log file for later usage, but the Hibernate SQL output also appeared in my Eclipse console (and I suppose will appear in Tomcat catalina.out later), and flushed my screen.

Is there any approach to avoid Hibernate Log on my console? Below is my log4j properties, and hibernate setting:

---

```
loghome=PATH_TO_LOG_DIRECTORY

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout,HB

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[IRIS-${project}][%p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n

log4j.logger.net.myapplication=info,warn,error
log4j.logger.debug=debug
log4j.appender.debug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n
log4j.appender.debug.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.debug.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.debug.append=true
log4j.appender.debug.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.debug.File=${loghome}/debug.log

log4j.logger.info=info
log4j.appender.info=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.info.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n
log4j.appender.info.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.info.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.info.append=true
log4j.appender.info.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.info.File=${loghome}/info.log

log4j.logger.warn=warn
log4j.appender.warn=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.warn.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.warn.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n
log4j.appender.warn.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.warn.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.warn.append=true
log4j.appender.warn.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.warn.File=${loghome}/warn.log

log4j.logger.error=error
log4j.appender.error=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.error.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n
log4j.appender.error.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.error.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.error.append=true
log4j.appender.error.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.error.File=${loghome}/error.log


log4j.appender.HB=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HB.layout.ConversionPattern=HB: [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [ Class = %C | Method = %M | Line = %L ] | %m |%n
log4j.appender.HB.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.HB.append=true
log4j.appender.HB.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.HB.File=${loghome}/hb.log

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=HB
```

---

Hibernate setting:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hydra.webapp.util.MySQL5MyISAMDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=<URL>
hibernate.connection.username=<USER>
hibernate.connection.password=<PASSWORD>
hibernate.connection.show_sql=false
dao.type=hibernate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you will have to set the additivity flag to false in order to prevent a logging event being sent to the parent (in this case a console logger). Check the

[Log4j Manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
 and [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html)

Comment: Thanks for response! I have added a new line for the additivity (log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false), but still my console is catching output from hibernate...